# XCode debugger hangs on breakpoints

Tags: xcode, debugging, gdb, breakpoints, xcode3.2

I'm debugging a project for iOS 4.0 (simulator) in XCode 3.2.3, and all of a sudden the debugger just stopped working on me. It will hit the first breakpoint and freeze. It will not respond to single stepping, continuing, pausing, etc.

I know I'm not the first person to complain about the XCode debugger, so does anyone have any sort of clue as to why this happens, or any sort of workaround? It has completely prevented me from getting anything done.

Answer (score 0):

I found that switching to build active target only and using llvm 1.5 worked for me. Even if llvm 1.5 can't be used for your final code, it can get  you around this extremely frustrating problem.