# Symbolic breakpoint on [UIViewController initWithCoder:] causes debugger to freeze

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

I am trying to set a symbolic breakpoint to detect when my view controllers are being unarchived. The breakpoint breaks properly on `[UIViewController initWithCoder:]` once the app is launched on my test device.

However, when I try to move past the breakpoint by pressing 'Continue' the debugger freezes: it stops responding to commands from Xcode (eg. 'pause' and 'stop') and the app itself hangs as well. I end up having to force quit and restart Xcode in order to relaunch the app.

The 'Step Into' functionality works as expected, but leads me directly into machine code - I'd like to be able to use the 'Continue' function to proceed with normal program execution. The app and debugger function normally if I disable this particular symbolic breakpoint.

Any insight into this problem would be helpful. I'm running Xcode 5.0.2 and using the LLDB debugger.

EDIT: I tried the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260396/xcode-debugger-hangs-on-breakpoints), but had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up setting the breakpoint to log a message to the console, and selected the 'automatically continue after evaluating' option.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug.  Can you take a sample of Xcode while it is frozen like this and file a bug with bugreporter.apple.com and include the sample?  Thanks.

Comment: Sure. I will try to replicate the problem and take a snapshot of Xcode.